Movie (Comedy?) where alien bug enters man's suit
I remember seeing this movie as a kid, maybe 5-15 years ago?! Two guys in (yellow?) suits walking through a isolated chamber full of small aliens animals and alien insects.
One small insect cut the suit of one of them and enter his skin. The man starts screaming as the insect starts crawling his leg from inside his skin. The doctors are taking him to a room to remove the insect, at first he doesn't want to, but then they tell him that the bug will reach his penis or butt, so he asks them to remove the bug immediately.
The movie seems a little Men in Black-ish, I'm 90% sure it's not one of them tough.
Also there is one alien in the chamber with a head that looks like a butt.

Possible duplicate of Movie with lots of different monsters with orange goop

I don't know how the duplicate rules work, but only the answer of that question was duplicate, but the question itself wasn't.

That's exactly how the dupe rule for identification questions work.

@cde No, it doesn't. It's only a dupe if the questions have any similarities, and they have none.

(And if anything, it's closer to this one.)

Sounds like Evolution with David Duchovny and Julianne Moore from 2001.

A fire-fighting cadet, two college professors, and a geeky but sexy government scientist work against an alien organism that has been rapidly evolving since its arrival on Earth inside a meteor. 

Here's most of the scene you described:



